# free-jqGrid column chooser with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, free-jqgrid, column-chooser

I can't find a way to get column chooser working with botstrap gui style.
`ui.multiselect.js` requires jquery UI widget components. Is there any example showing how to replace these and have a 'bootstrap only' column chooser?

Comment: You are right. There is currently no `columnChooser` or other methods from  grid.jqueryui.js module which works without any jQuery UI files. One have to include both Boostrap and jQuery UI (at least some modules of jQuery UI) to be able to use `columnChooser`. One can use `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` together with jQuery UI theme, which looks close to Boostrap theme, which you use. It's not very nice, but it works.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but someone asked me if this approach is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/ckvyhr2x/13/ you can see columnchooser is shown but not in correct way. I think some css classes need adjusting. Is there an example now to show bootstrap4 working grid with column chooser.